# How can I extract a word after # symbol in Python String

Tags: python

Given a sentence, e.g. "Im SHORTING #RSR here", I need to extract word that follow the "#" symbol (from, and not including the "#", to the next space).

Obviously, the "#" symbol can be anywhere in the string.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Split on space, 2. Iterate on array, 3. Use startswith and substring, 4. Get the word needed, 5. Go give yourself a treat! // *6. Think about how to do it in one pass.*

Comment: Regex: `\B\#\w+`

Comment: Are you trying to remove just the characters after the `#`? Or remove the entire `#RSR` substring? Or are you trying to extract the words starting with `#`?

Comment: Your example `word` is more like a sentence…

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
sentence = "Im SHORTING #RSR here"
words = [word.lstrip('#') for word in sentence.split() if word.startswith('#')]
```

The result will contain all hashtaged words in the sentence.
If there's always exactly one, just use `words[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
phrase = 'Im SHORTING #RSR here'

# split the input on spaces
words = phrase.split(' ')

# init empty list
comments = []

# iterate through each word
for word in words:
    # check if the first letter of the word is '#'
    if word[0] == '#':
        # add the comment to the list of comments
        comments.append(word)

# let's see what we have!
print(comments)
```

Comment: I believe the OP *wants* the words starting with `#`.

Comment: The question is too unclear for me to be sure here, what language suggests that he wants the words? `cut the word after "#" symbol` sounds like he wants to cut out these words.

Comment: Thanks, I need to extract the word RSR,

Comment: I've edited my answer to extract rather than remove.